# Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804

Tags: oracle

I am having an issue to connect my C++ application to my Oracle DB,I get an error

> `"[OracleException] errcode: 1804, desc: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804".`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving `ORA-01804` by the database, the description of `ORA-01804` is:

```
failure to initialize timezone information
Cause:   The timezone information file was not properly read.
```

Comment: I am getting the same error can you please elaborate how you were able to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: There is no RCA and fix for this issue

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error for cx_oracle (via python). For this specific case ORACLE_HOME was missing in environment variables.
Set Oracle_home with Windows Cli (use your oracle folder):

```
setx ORACLE_HOME  "C:\oracle\oc121\"
```

On some of the DB connections TNS_ADMIN is required also set that as well:

```
setx TNS_ADMIN "%ORACLE HOME%\network\admin"
```

Answer (score 5):

I use OCCI in CentOS 7, and encounter the same issue, just add libociicus.so to LD_LIBRARY_PATH to resolve the issue.

Comment: Indeed, libociicus.so solves two problems. (1) the missing timezone file (2) the missing text for ORA-01804.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing such trouble with C++ OCCI application which caught `oracle::occi::SQLException` when it was trying to connect to oracle db.

```
ORA-01804:
failure to initialize timezone information
Cause:  The timezone information file was not properly read.
```

The reason was that my linux oracle client was missing some timezone related files in its `$ORACLE_HOME` directory. 
The solution was to simply copy those files from another instance of oracle client.

Comment: Can  you please specify the missing files

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `libociicus.so` library was missing. It can be found in [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html).

Comment: I can no longer see this so file in the instant client.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible reason: Binary have no permission to access the OCCI library ...
I encounter such situation due to my mistakenly setting mode of folder in which OCCI library is.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but there are no answers can fix my case (**oracledb** package of nodejs, macOS).

but, again, I found a solution for myself.

The solution is that move `libociei.dylib` into `/usr/locale/lib` folder. That's it.

Comment: You can also adapt your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly. The main change nowadays, and why your answer hints towards the right solution, is that the missing library mentioned in older answers seems to have been replaced by `libociei` which currently measures a hefty 137MB alone. No idea what Oracle does, but it's definitely obscene to have such a huge library dependencies to simply invoke `sqlplus` to quickly bootstrap some SQL scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Another trivial yet hard to determine cause for this might be that Oracle installation folder is incomplete. For me, a reason for this was that some process just (unsuccessfully) uninstalled Oracle client.

It was really tricky as bin folder from PATH env. var contained oci.dll (and lots of other DLL-s), but elsewhere under `C:\oracle\11\` there were other files missing.

So: check that installation folder contains all required files!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's because the version of my instant client and the database server is using a different version. So I had to match their version to solve this error. Apparently, Oracle can't read the DB timezone if their version is different.

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't really a good solution. I'm not sure myself what made the deal. But for me the solution was to:

- drop all other oracle clients from my PC
- clear ORACLE_HOME and PATH from paths to dropped clients
- restart the PC

After that the error was gone