# Can't connect with cx_Oracle of Python to oracle remote database

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I issue this statement: `db = cx_Oracle.connect("user/pass@IP/BKTDW")`

and I get this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804

It seems that connect method doen't work at all. I have installed the Oracle Client and I am connecting normally via Toad or Sql Developer.

Please Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837811/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the ORACLE_HOME variable in the system variables and also add the bin directory in the PATH system variable. THNX

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that **sqlplus** is working from cmd line. It could be if on **64bit** windows in has in PATH there is a target to non-64 bin version of oracle bin folder. In our case we ensured that 64bit location is placed in **PATH** . For instance place `c:\Oracle\Ora11g_r2_x64\bin\`  and remove `c:\Oracle\ora11g_2\bin\`, it was **not related** with ORACLE_HOME .