# Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804 python in unix

Tags: python, unix, cx-oracle

I wanted to set the environment variables in the unix for my python scrippting project that uses cx_Oracle to connect with the database and have CRUD operations.

i have used os.environ to set the environment variables for oracle. all the libraries are present in the corresponding directory.

This is the method i have used to set the environment variables is unix

```
def set_environment():
    os.environ["TNS_ADMIN"]="/opt/oracle/orafmw/product/11.2.0.1/client_1/network/admin"
    os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = "opt/oracle/orafmw/product/11.2.0.1/client_1"
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/opt/oracle/orafmw/product/11.2.0.1/client_1/lib"
    os.environ["PATH"] = "$PATH:/opt/oracle/orafmw/product/11.2.0.1/client_1/bin:."
```

and i have called the method from the main method of my script.

```
def get_connect_string():
    return db_username+'/'+password+'@'+host+':'+port+'/'+service_name

def main():
    import os
    import cx_Oracle
    set_environment()
    query = "SELECT * FROM SITE WHERE SITE_CODE = :1"
    try:
        connect_string = get_connect_string()
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connect_string)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        d = cur.execute(query, ["AUS"]).fetchone()
        conn.commit()
        if d:
            data = (([i[0] for i in cur.description]), d)
        else:
            data = None
    except Exception as e:
        print("error in operation : ", e)
        conn.rollback()
    finally:
        conn.close()
        print(data)
```

The error message i am getting is:

```
Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804
```

Comment: How are you calling Oracle? None of the code in your question would seem to directly produce this error. Do you get a traceback?

Comment: i just added the rest of the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837811/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804

Comment: I have these files in this location. product/11.2.0.1/client_1/oracore/zoneinfo$ 
Do you think its a timezone related problem?



 
```
readme.txt
timezdif.csv
timezlrg_6.dat
timezlrg_5.dat
timezlrg_4.dat
timezlrg_3.dat
timezlrg_2.dat
timezlrg_1.dat
timezlrg_11.dat
timezlrg_10.dat
timezone_9.dat
timezone_8.dat
timezone_7.dat
timezone_6.dat
timezone_5.dat
timezone_4.dat
timezone_3.dat
timezone_2.dat
timezone_1.dat
timezone_11.dat
timezone_10.dat
timezlrg_9.dat
timezlrg_8.dat
timezlrg_7.dat
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837811/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804)

Answer (score 0):

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable cannot be set from within your application. It must be set before the process is started! Otherwise, it will not take effect. The error you are getting indicates that the environment isn't set properly. Try setting the environment variables **before** running your script and see if that resolves the issue for you!