cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01804 on Windows Server
I am currently facing an issue while trying to connect to databases using cx_Oracle on windows server. I have set ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly. However, I am encountering the following error when I run my script
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804
Here are the steps I have taken so far
1.Verified that ORACLE_HOME is set to the correct Oracle client installation directory
2.Confirmed that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the Oracle client's library directory.
3.Ensured that PyCharm is running with the correct environment variables.
Despite these measures, the error persists. Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated
Here are the steps I have taken so far
1.Verified that ORACLE_HOME is set to the correct Oracle client installation directory
2.Confirmed that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the Oracle client's library directory.
3.Ensured that PyCharm is running with the correct environment variables.

Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12837811/1509264

make this much easier on yourself and use new new oracle python driver which requires NO oracle client/homes or ld_library_path setup. See this https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html

Ditto what @thatjeffsmith said.  Aside from that, you appear to be setting Linux environment variables on Windows.  Follow the installation instructions closely: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-python-oracledb-on-windows Unset variables you don't need / shouldn't have, e.g. never set ORACLE_HOME when using Instant Client, if that's the client you are using.
